# Difference between Q-learning and G-learning in Reinforcement Learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, unsupervised-learning

What is the difference between Q-learning and G-learning in Reinforcement Learning? Please explain with formulas.

An example [source](https://deepai.org/publication/g-learner-and-girl-goal-based-wealth-management-with-reinforcement-learning):

> Instead of relying on a utility of consumption, we present G-Learner: a reinforcement learning algorithm that operates with explicitly defined one-step rewards, does not assume a data generation process, and is suitable for noisy data. Our approach is based on G-learning - a probabilistic extension of the Q-learning method of reinforcement learning. In this paper, we demonstrate how G-learning, when applied to a quadratic reward and Gaussian reference policy, gives an entropy-regulated Linear Quadratic Regulator (LQR).

Answer (score 0):

Shortly said, they differ in the value function they optimize:

- [Q-learning](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/q-learnings) estimates the optimal action-value function (Q-function) and directly learns the values associated with state-action pairs.
- G-learning estimates the optimal value function (V-function) and focuses on learning the values associated with states.

These [reinforcement learning](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/reinforcement-learnings) algorithms are comparable in that they try to find an optimal policy by optimising their value functions. [Q-Learning](https://databasecamp.de/en/ml/q-learnings) is used when you have a discrete action space. This is why it includes the actions in its value function. G-Learning is more suitable for continuous action spaces.